# When both a proxy and a VPN are enabled, how is network traffic routed?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, proxy

Due to work requirements, a network proxy software（V2rayN） is installed on the computer and a VPN (globalVPN) is also enabled. When visiting a website, how is the network forwarded? Does it go through the VPN first and then the proxy, or does it go through the proxy first and then the VPN, or are there other situations?

When I set the proxy route to whitelist and visit [www.ip138.com](http://www.ip138.com), the website shows my address as the VPN’s IP; when I set the proxy route to** global** and visit [www.ip138.com](http://www.ip138.com), the website shows my address as the proxy server’s IP.
this is [whitelist config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cj2J.jpg)and [global configimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZyI8.jpg).

Comment: Are you connecting to the proxy then the VPN or the VPN then the proxy? Please [edit] your question with enough information to answer your question.

Comment: It depends on your setup.  Generally speaking a VPN works at a lower level then a proxy, so a proxy is likely to be routed on top of the VPN. IE the vpn provider will see the IP address of the proxy.

Comment: so the terms "whitelist" and "**global**" are not really standard terms for VPNs. in terms of your results, the first outcome is clearly not what you want, since the proxy is irrelevant if the outcome is they see the VPN (or your local pub IP). the second outcome is non-indicative however since you have no means to tell if the traffic passed through the VPN to reach the proxy. anything more you can tell us about the nature of the "whitelist" or route "mode=global" features would be helpful. I'd assume a "whitelist" is a bypass list, but the outcome indicates its the opposite. odd

Comment: @FrankThomas I have uploaded pictures of whitelist and global, please take a look.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but i am not able to read that language/alphabet. Hopefully someone who can will be able to help.